# Is there any tutorials on how to drag a file form a flex application to windows explorer?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder4.5

I can't seem to find a tutorial on how to create a drag event that allows you to drag a file form a flex air application into windows explorer file system. 
Is this possible? I have a icon that i would like to be able to click on and drag from my air application info the file system and create a text file in that location that i drug into.
Does anyone know of a tutorial or a example to get me started?

Comment: This looks promising have you looked into it? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/air/desktop/URLFilePromise.html#URLFilePromise%28%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find one that was exactly what I was looking for if you download tour de FLEX (its a bunch of flex tutorials in a air application) http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex.html  It that one called "Drag and Drop (2)" Its about dragging form inside a air application to the file system and back very helpful!
Thank you everyone!